# mongoexport keep order of objects in inner array field

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Hi I am trying to find a way to keep order of objects in inner array while mongoexport operation. I am using mongodb 3.0.2.

Here is the schema;

```
mongoose.Schema({
    parity: {
        type: String
    },
    exchange: String,
    interval: String,
    dataSet: [{
        open: Number,
        high: Number,
        low: Number,
        close: Number,
        date: Date,
        btcVolume: Number,
        _id: false
    }],
    _id: {
        type: String
    }
})
```

So, basically I want to keep order `dataSet` array based on `date` field. The problem is mongoexport doesn't preserve the order even though dataSet is ordered in each document I have.

I am playing around with this query but couldn't make it.

```
> mongoexport -q '{ $query: {parity: "BTC-STRAT"}, $orderby: {"dataSet.date": -1} }' -d crypto -c stockentities --out strat.json
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$orderby` doesn't sort items within the array. It sorts documents. In your case it picks an item with latest `date` from `dataSet` array for each document and sort documents by this value in descending order.

mongoexport preserves order of element within `dataSet` as it is stored in the original document.

Comment: Alex it seems that you are right. Order changes when use sort in push query. which is `$push: { dataSet: { $each: prevDataList, $sort: {"dataSet.date" : 1}}}` do you have an idea? or should I open another question for this?

Comment: I replaced `dataSet.date` with `date` which fixed the issue.